# Magento2.3.5: How to get Customer Grid custom columns values in CSV?

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, magento2.3.1, magento2.3.4, magento2.3.5

I want to to add custom columns values in export option in customer grid, but only heading are showing in csv file not values.

here is my customer grid custom columns.

> Vendor\Module/view/adminhtml/ui_component/customer_listing.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <columns name="customer_columns" class="Magento\Customer\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns">
        <column name="loyal_member_since" class="Vendor\Module\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\LoyalMemberSince">
            <settings>
                <filter>dateRange</filter>
                <label translate="true">Loyal Member Since</label>
                <sortable>true</sortable>
                <sorting>asc</sorting>
                <dataType>date</dataType>
            </settings>
        </column>
        <column name="loyalty_tier" class="Vendor\Module\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\Tier">
            <settings>
                <filter>textRange</filter>
                <label translate="true">Tier</label>
                <sortable>true</sortable>
                <sorting>asc</sorting>
                <dataType>text</dataType>
            </settings>
        </column>
        <column name="loyalty_welcome" class="Vendor\Module\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\Welcome">
            <settings>
                <filter>boolean</filter>
                <label translate="true">Welcome</label>
                <sortable>true</sortable>
                <sorting>asc</sorting>
                <dataType>select</dataType>
            </settings>
        </column>
        <column name="devices_registered" class="Vendor\Module\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\DeviceRegistration">
            <settings>
                <filter>number</filter>
                <label translate="true">Device registration</label>
                <sortable>true</sortable>
                <sorting>asc</sorting>
                <dataType>text</dataType>
            </settings>
        </column>
        <column name="new_neo_subscription" class="Vendor\Module\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\NewNeoSubscription">
            <settings>
                <filter>boolean</filter>
                <label translate="true">New neo subscription</label>
                <sortable>true</sortable>
                <sorting>asc</sorting>
                <dataType>select</dataType>
            </settings>
        </column>
        <column name="loyalty_happy_birthday" class="Vendor\Module\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\HappyBirthday">
            <settings>
                <filter>boolean</filter>
                <label translate="true">Happy birthday</label>
                <sortable>true</sortable>
                <sorting>asc</sorting>
                <dataType>select</dataType>
            </settings>
        </column>
        <column name="loyalty_purchases" class="Vendor\Module\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\PurchasesId">
            <settings>
                <filter>textRange</filter>
                <label translate="true">Purchases</label>
                <sortable>true</sortable>
                <sorting>asc</sorting>
                <dataType>text</dataType>
            </settings>
        </column>
        <column name="premium_accessories" class="Vendor\Module\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\PremiumAccessories">
            <settings>
                <filter>boolean</filter>
                <label translate="true">Premium accessories</label>
                <sortable>true</sortable>
                <sorting>asc</sorting>
                <dataType>select</dataType>
            </settings>
        </column>
        <column name="free_device" class="Vendor\Module\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\FreeDevice">
            <settings>
                <filter>boolean</filter>
                <label translate="true">Free device</label>
                <sortable>true</sortable>
                <sorting>asc</sorting>
                <dataType>select</dataType>
            </settings>
        </column>
        <column name="warranty_extension" class="Vendor\Module\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\WarrantyExtension">
            <settings>
                <filter>boolean</filter>
                <label translate="true">Warranty extension</label>
                <sortable>true</sortable>
                <sorting>asc</sorting>
                <dataType>select</dataType>
            </settings>
        </column>
        <column name="redeemed_points" class="Vendor\Module\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\RedeemPoints">
            <settings>
                <filter>textRange</filter>
                <label translate="true">Redeem points</label>
                <sortable>true</sortable>
                <sorting>asc</sorting>
                <dataType>text</dataType>
            </settings>
        </column>
        <column name="unsubscription_date" class="Vendor\Module\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\Unsubscription">
            <settings>
                <filter>dateRange</filter>
                <label translate="true">Unsubscription</label>
                <sortable>true</sortable>
                <sorting>asc</sorting>
                <dataType>date</dataType>
            </settings>
        </column>
        <column name="deals_redeemed" class="Vendor\Module\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\Deals">
            <settings>
                <filter>textRange</filter>
                <label translate="true">Deals</label>
                <sortable>true</sortable>
                <sorting>asc</sorting>
                <dataType>select</dataType>
            </settings>
        </column>
    </columns>
</listing>
```

**but when i export csv this is what i get**
[image]
[image]

**i only get default columns values but custom columns just heading  no values**

- any idea how to do this?

Comment: https://meetanshi.com/blog/include-custom-column-in-export-to-csv-in-magento-2/

Comment: that solution didn't worked

Comment: any error ?????

Comment: No error, just nothing in csv file